# Different admin URL for each website - Magento 2.1.1

Tags: magento-2.1.1, multi-website, admin-url

I trying to configure M2 (2.1.1) multiwebsite.

I already created separate websites/stores/views for each website, I also configured vhosts, M2 admin config and .htaccess. All websites are works fine except one thing.. admin login URL. How to set up this URLs like this:

**example.com/admin** - root M2 website admin login works fine

**example2.com/admin** - other M2 website admin login

Now, if i trying to access **example2.com** i get  errors : http://pastebin.com/VbCqGzSV

Here you have my other setting:

**.htaccess config:**

```
###########################################
## settings fot webiste example2.com
## WEBSITE CODE: example2com
SetEnvIf Host .*example2.com.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=example2com
SetEnvIf Host .*example2.com.* MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
###########################################


## example2.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)example2\.com
RewriteRule .* – [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:example2com]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)example2\.com
RewriteRule .* – [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website]
## END OF: example2.com
```

Also vHost config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot        /var/www/html/example2
    ServerName example2.com
    SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "example2com"
    SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "website"
</VirtualHost>
```

Configuration of Example2.com Website:
[image: Configuration of Example2.com Website:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lyczos, magento **does not have this type of feature**.

In magento admin, is also a store.As per as, **magento store max 1 url**.So you cannot use **different admin urls for each websites**