# Different admin URLs for each website - Magento 2.4

Tags: admin, magento2.4, multi-website, websites

I have a Magento 2.4 instance that serves as the main website for my company. Also, I have multiple clients that want to have a website similar to mine but with different categories, products, and pages, all of them under the same admin interface.

In order to fulfill this request, I created multiple websites under the same admin interface, serving each website from different domains. Also, I assigned a different root category for each store and everything works perfectly. I intend to use an advanced permissions module as well so that I can restrict access to different websites/sections.

However, I have one question related to creating different admin URLs per website. I tried to make it happen by changing the values under Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Admin Base URL, but that menu is only available for the "Default Config" view. If I switch the view to "Website", it doesn't show.

How can I achieve this goal (if possible)?

Comment: Nope: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140440/different-admin-url-for-each-website-magento-2-1-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento not provided this type of feature.

In magento admin, is also a store. As per as, magento store max 1 url.So you cannot use different admin urls for each websites But you can use different admin User with User Roll. So it's usefull to you.